# How do I optimize ActiveRecord queries and speed up my HAML partial which is rendered 1000 times in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I have a HAML partial that is rendered as part of a collection, which itself renders two other partials. The collection could be 1000 long. It uses complex queries with group by and `#map` and `#reject`. How do I speed this render up? It's already taking about 6 seconds for 100. I've already tried using .includes(:relation) in the top query but it didn't help. Despite including `.includes(:votes, :comments, :taggings, :tags)`, and running `SELECT "votes".* FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."post_id" IN (124, 123,...`, it still tries to load individual relations `Vote Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "votes".* FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."post_id" = $1 AND "votes"."user_id" = 1`. I suppose ActiveRecord doesn't use a relational object cache like Coherence (which is fine as that is difficult).

<strike>(As an aside, how do I extract the complex query code that is a couple lines in the partial? There is no controller for an intermediate partial. I'm afraid if I add mobile templates, I will have to copy the complex query and keep it in synch, which will no doubt fail.)</strike>

Here is the layout of the calls

```
-- User
  -- SQL: @user.posts.order(:created_at => :desc).limit(1000)
  -- Post
    -- SQL, Votes, post.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    -- SQL, Comments, post.comments.count
    -- SQL, Tags, post.taggings.select("tag_id, count(*) as count").group("tag_id").order(count: :desc).limit(3).includes(:tag)
  -- SQL, Comments... about the same as above
```

This blog describes almost *exactly* the same problem I'm having! However, they use `:finder_sql` and when I tried to use that, Rails complained and said it was deprecated and to look at scopes. Scopes doesn't appear to help any. They are neat, but they only restrict queries instead of loading additional information in one query. 
http://coldattic.info/shvedsky/pro/blogs/a-foo-walks-into-a-bar/posts/75

Comment: Are you saying your complex query code is inside the partial?  Shouldn't this be in the model?  Does the speed problem have to do with the rendering or is this a problem with queries?  Would need to see a more concrete example to see where the problem is.

Comment: It sounds like you are probably querying and instantiating a lot of models which is costly, I would suggest you use SQL ie subquery to find only the models you want.

Comment: @riley Ok I unrolled the loop and included the partials into the main `show.haml`, and moved the queries into the model, but I don't think that's the problem. It didn't seem to help. I think the problem is with the SQL and it fetching additional info for each of the 1000 posts. I'll update the question with the layout.

Comment: @riley For some reason I thought the SQL should go into the controller. Normally I like my models to be very simple. Not sure why I didn't think of putting the SQL into the model.

Comment: Paste the code for this action from the controller.

Comment: @omarvelous I pretty much did already paste the code. `def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @posts = @user.posts.order(:created_at => :desc).limit(1000).includes(:votes, :comments, :taggings, :tags)
  end`

Comment: I think part of the problem is you are including votes... when you really only want votes for each post by the current user... You see how that is two different requests? So for 1000 posts, you will need to find the votes by the current_user for each post THEN it will use the cache to (should) to populate the renders. I'd advise against loading 1000 anything, even if you do get the speed you are looking for, the rendering in your browser will be painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got an idea from the blog I mentioned. I got it down to milliseconds! Their solution was deprecated but they also mentioned `find_by_sql`, which is what I used. I could create my bespoke queries and it would add additional fields to the model that were in the select clause. I'm quite disheartened that I had to un-factor my HAML templates and customize them specifically for this page, causing duplication. :( My templates were a thing of beauty and I was amazed the whole site could fit in such few lines.

```
sql = <<-EOL
  select posts.id, posts.user_id, posts.title, ...
    users.username,
    (select vote from votes ...) as user_votes,
    coalesce((select sum(vote) from votes ...),0) as votes_sum,
    (select count(*) from comments ...) as comments_count
    from posts inner join users on posts.user_id = users.id
    where users.id = ?
    order by created_at desc
    limit 1000 
EOL
@posts = Post.find_by_sql [sql, (current_user ? current_user.id : -1), params[:id]]
postIds = @posts.map { |p| p.id }
sql = <<-EOL
  select tags.id, tags.tag, taggings.post_id, count(*) as count 
    from tags inner join taggings on tags.id = taggings.tag_id 
    where taggings.post_id in (?)
    group by tags.id, tags.tag, taggings.post_id
    order by count desc
EOL
@tags = Tag.find_by_sql [sql, postIds]
sql = <<-EOL
  select comments.id, comments.user_id, ...
    (select vote from votes where ...) as user_votes,
    coalesce((select sum(vote) from votes ...),0) as votes_sum,
    (select count(*) from comments ...) as has_children
  from comments
  where comments.user_id = ?
  order by created_at desc
  limit 1000 
EOL
@comments = Comment.find_by_sql [sql, (current_user ? current_user.id : -1), params[:id] ]
```

The tags were especially challenging because I needed the top 3 out of possible thousands. There's no easy way to do that in SQL without having 3 sub-selects for tag1, tag2, tag3, but I thought that would be even slower than an additional query. However the tags are now non-related to posts, so I had to use pure Ruby with `select` and `first` to get the right ones.

Another comment mentioned `connnection.execute(sql)` which I might try to get even faster, bypassing models completely. I might lose a little more faith in Rails if so... :(

I found `image_tag` took up a large portion of time! Converting to plain HTML sped it up tremendously!

I went to Chrome debugger on the Network tab and right clicked on the request and selected 'Copy CURL' to get the request, then I could run and benchmark it from the command line.

```
$ time for i in {1..10}; do curl -I "http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/1" -H "If-None-Match: ""37d7cd0d7d37f5af51168561c2ef04e2""" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "Cookie: _Tyger_session=Y3oydVZ5OE1KMXl6cHNWL0dwNnU3bTQzNlpuaERtemRSZ3g5T3FoV2pPdEErejllVDRmME9EVGVuTkZVa1l3eDhRMmx3QXplTCtmT0xQTlFYNGhvbzJlUXVGRFc1a3BsWG1ZWThIRDE5WmVnZ2czU2NnMkRPQ0xIc1RJd3gxMm5wMUxWUEMyQUQxa1EzYzl5b3lMSDhsckd6WWJnYTJnUm96NEl4b3Q3MmdmSE1pbzE2NjF5b040SnB6TEk1WjZoSU5jYjI5V0xDSWwvMlJ3c2llOHBISmp0YlpCRGdxcnhNTWtNMXRyT3piYz0tLXdFNkpTVjFHeThTckJNNk1HU3N2NWc9PQ"%"3D"%"3D--21e668fceab201c65260d8afebce1b24728d6055" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --compressed -s | grep X-Runtime; done
X-Runtime: 0.307203
X-Runtime: 0.305202
X-Runtime: 0.313207
X-Runtime: 0.310206
X-Runtime: 0.303202
X-Runtime: 0.332220
X-Runtime: 0.312222
X-Runtime: 0.304202
X-Runtime: 0.308239
X-Runtime: 0.315209

real    0m3.449s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.258s
```

Answer (score 2):

As one of the speed up solutions -- you may try getting rid of extra partials and couple all of them withing first, main partial. Calling for `` `render `` is quite "expensive", so you may pay some code 'de-organisation' for speed up.

Comment: Ok I unrolled the loop and inserted the partial HAMLs directly into `show.haml`, but it didn't help too much. I think the problem is the SQL. With PHP or Perl I could create a giant JOIN query and load everything in a loop creating my own objects. Not sure how to optimize ActiveRecord.

Comment: You can use pure SQL requests within Rails as well (use ```connection.execute(sql_query)``` in your controller.

Comment: Ok I optimized both the unrolled and refactored HAML, no extra SQL between either, and using `render` on an array is TWICE as slow!

Answer (score 0):

"How do I speed up X?" is not something answerable without code available for review. As a general note, though, you can use [fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) to increase the speed of retrieving partials.

Additionally, you can use 'Model Caching' as [described in this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/115-model-caching-revised) to cache query results.

For the second part of your question, you can extract the query into a Query Object as described at [this codeclimate blog post](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/)

Comment: I can speed up the code myself, I just don't know how to do it with HAML and partials and Rails. I've written monster SQL queries that would make Dostoevsky faint! The fragment caching is interesting, but each partial would be dynamic with different titles. It is just visible per user and I'm not worried about reloads, just initial loads. So it's low volume but high cost and private. I'll read up on the other links now, thanks!